# Openfire server installed in AWS EC2 stop working unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp, openfire

Needing som expert help with our  server that doesn’t work properly.

Setup.

AWS ec2 Server

Openfire 4.1.1

MySQL 5.7 (Standard DB)

Users: around 200 between “normal” working hours

The problem is that (mostly) "once" in a day the server stops working, no logins are processed but the webinterface are working.

The only solution we’ve found is to restart the whole server.

But the problem continues.

Does anyone have a clue were we should begin to find a solution?

Kind regards,

Alpa Bhanderi

Comment: Have you checked all the log files? Is there anything useful being printed in any of the files?

Comment: When the server is in a state that it stopped working, try making a thread dump (see https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/jvm-settings-and-debugging/49010 ) and report back please. That thread dump might tell us what the server is being locked up on.